# How to nest qraphql resolvers so as to group them

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-tools

I'm wrapping a series of REST APIs in GraphQL and I'm having trouble getting a resolver to work.

My typeDefs

```js
const typeDefs = `
  type Page {
    id: String
    path: String!
    title: String!
    heading: String
    type: String
    html: String
    summary: String
  }

  type Site {
    page(path: String!): Page
  }

  type Query {
    site: Site
  }`
```

and my resolvers

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    site: {
      page: async (_root, { path }) => getPage(path)
    }
  }
}
```

If I try this query

```
{
  site {
    page(path: "/services/research-request") {
      id
      path
      title
      html
      type
      summary
    }
  }
}
```

I get back

```
{
  "data": {
    "site": null
  }
}
```

However if I don't nest the page within the site

```js
const typeDefs = `
  type Page {
    id: String
    path: String!
    title: String!
    heading: String
    type: String
    html: String
    summary: String
  }

  type Query {
    page(path: String!): Page
  }`
```

and use resolvers

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    page: async (_root, { path }) => getPage(path)
  }
}
```

then I try this query

```
{
  page(path: "/services/research-request") {
    id
    path
    title
    html
    type
    summary
  }
}
```

I get back, correctly,

```
{
  "data": {
    "page": {
      "id": "d290f1ee-6c54-4b01-90e6-d701748f0851",
      "path": "/services/research-request",
      "title": "Research | Requests",
      "html": "<p>This is a really well put together Research Requests page<p>\n",
      "type": "page",
      "summary": "A short piece of summary text"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm going to be pulling in data from a number of APIs to populate my graph so wanted to group the various parts according to `site` vs `user`, etc but I'm missing something obvious when trying to nest the resolvers.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No 'free' nesting in graphql ... nest > next level depth > next TYPE ... site resolver, site.page resolver ... but also own site id (for client cache), rebuild/adjust all clients code etc. ...

Namespacing should be better: `sitePage`, `siteOptions`, `userProfile`, `userSettings` ... use alias (or replace in files) for renaming in client.